# Declaration of variable with variable in bash

Tags: bash, variables, for-loop

```
#!/bin/sh
b=( a b c d )
count=1
for a in ${b[@]}; do
    example_$count=$a  # how do I declare this variable "example_$count"
    echo example_$count; # and how do I echo it
    (( count++ ))
done
```

What I need is something like this:

```
$example_1=a 
$example_2=b 
$example_3=c 
$example_4=d
```

Comment: why do you want to do this? Why not just use the array? For example, `$example_1` would correspond to `${b[0]}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For declaring variables, you use `eval`. For displaying variables, you have two solutions : `eval`, or Bash syntax `${!var}`.

So your script becomes, with only `eval` :

```
#!/bin/bash
b=( a b c d )
count=1
for a in ${b[@]}; do
    var=example_$count
    eval $var=$a
    eval echo \$$var
    (( count++ ))
done
```

Or with Bash syntax for display :

```
#!/bin/bash
b=( a b c d )
count=1
for a in ${b[@]}; do
    var=example_$count
    eval $var=$a
    echo ${!var}
    (( count++ ))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution:

```
example=( a b c d )
```

Instead of `$example_1`, just use `${example[0]}`. At first glance, this may not look like what you want. But keep in mind that BASH is a scripting language with a history (= it has many, many quirks). So while it's not exactly what you think you need, it will work as you expect in most cases.

One reason might be that you think that [arrays should start with index of 1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm) (which is a common beginners mistake that causes lots of problems later). But if you insist, you can insert an empty 0 element to simulate the desired behavior:

```
example=( "" a b c d )
```

of if you already have the array:

```
example=( "" "${example[@]}" ) # prepend empty element to existing array
```